# How can i configure Apache and IIS together 

Tags: apache, iis

Can any one help me .....

When i close the Apache service then also the IIS server is not working ..
is ther any way to run IIS whn apache is install ....

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/69522/can-i-install-apache-and-iis-together-on-same-computer

Comment: I just closed this as off-topic since it really belongs on Server Fault, but I don't want to create a duplicate by migrating.  The links that are already here should help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just have to have one of them listening on another port.  By default IIS listens on Port 80, if port 80 is taken then it will have troubles.

The easiest way would be to put apache on port 8080 and let IIS have 80... then http://localhost will point to IIS and http://localhost:8080 will point to apache.

Comment: http://localhost/WE_Project/Myshoppe.html ... this is my page

Comment: but still error i... i changed the port to 8080 .. for apache but error on above link

Comment: what must be the reason .. i use windows 7 ..... but i dont think this may cause any error\

Comment: which server did you change the port?  Did you restart both?

Comment: i change the Apache server port ... and restarted both ...

Comment: can apache do the work of IIS for asp file to run ...

Comment: Probably not... have you checked the error logs on apache?  Will both not work, or just one?  Have you tried by starting just one and seeing if they work individually?

Comment: ya i tried to work individually but  the iis is not working ... i dont wat may b the reason but i hav install it perfectly ...

Comment: i saw the link http://serverfault.com/questions/69522/can-i-install-apache-and-iis-together-on-same-computer but i am not getting this..... You have an ethernet card with an IP 10.10.10.10 and localhost 127.0.0.1. Configure Apache to listen on 127.0.0.1 and configure IIS to listen on 10.10.10.10 or vice versa. Then, edit your hosts file to point example.org to 127.0.0.1 and example.com to 10.10.10.10 or vice versa.

This way, you do not need to tell your browser to connect to http://localhost:8080 or anything like that, not that there is anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Run Apache and IIS at the Same Time](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/07/15/run-apache-iis-same-pc-2/)